# Wubi keeps freezing. REISUB doesn't work. Any safe, easily undoable alternatives?

Tags: dual-boot, wubi, windows-7, acer

I ran the installation for Wubi from ubuntu.com on my Acer Aspire One 722. It works fine every now and then, but more often than not the OS freezes. Every time it freezes I attempt the REISUB method, but I don't even get the console, just a frozen desktop. I can't pinpoint where exactly it freezes. I've been able to run Firefox and browse the web without problems multiple times, so from what I understand that discounts the problem with the network card others were having. But the freeze occurs either right away or after a while, maybe when I'm downloading something.

I have tried a fresh install, unless you think I should redownload the setup file again, but that seems pointless. The REISUB method worked ONCE. And I don't even think it was when the OS was frozen. I'm pretty sure I just did that to make sure the method wasn't some "Alt+F4" beeswax.

I have considered using a virtual PC, but I don't want to have to choose what fraction of my RAM (2GB total) goes to Ubuntu, I want 100% of it to go to Ubuntu when I want to run Ubuntu. When I want to run Ubuntu, I want to run ONLY Ubuntu, and when I want to run Windows, I want to run ONLY Windows.

I really like the idea of choosing which OS I want to boot into when I start up my computer, but I don't want to have to do any partitioning, to do something I can't undo easily.

Is there an alternative to Wubi that would allow me to do what I want, or is Wubi my only way? If it's the only way, how can I make it WORK?!

Answer (score 0):

REISUB only works 95% of the time, the other 5% is when the kernel "breaks". 
Try either updating or downgrading the latest kernel. If that doesn’t work, a reinstallation would probably fix it. 
Install synaptic if you prefer a graphical way to remove/downgrade the kernel, or use apt-get to remove it. 
Just make sure that no matter what you leave a kernel installed. Good luck.

Also partitioning is pretty easy to reverse for the most part, but it may seem scary for one who hasnt done it before. If you can have a friend sit with you who has done it successfully before, it may help alot. Just try to keep a Windows recovery disk.